# Grep for literal strings

Tags: unix, grep

I'm after a grep-type tool to search for purely literal strings.  I'm looking for the occurrence of a line of a log file, as part of a line in a seperate log file.  The search text can contain all sorts of regex special characters, e.g., `[]().*^$-\`.

Is there a Unix search utility which would not use regex, but just search for literal occurrences of a string?

Comment: Wonder why the question wasn't _"Can I make `grep` search for literal strings?"_ instead of _"Is there something like `grep` that can search for literal strings?"_ Flat-head screwdrivers can fit Philips screw-heads, you know `;)`

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can use grep for that, with the -F option.

```
-F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated fixed strings
```

Comment: *"newline-separated fixed strings"* How can I do this on the terminal prompt? I know I can create a pattern file, but without a file, is it possible to do on the prompt? Pressing Enter obviously executes the command.

Comment: *I will answer my own question. :)* You just need to provide the multiple fixed strings using repeats of the `-e` option. Like this: `grep -F -e "fixed1" -e "fixed2" -e "fixed3" -e "fixed4"`. No newlines required ;)

Comment: Not available on Solaris. Instead `fgrep` is used.

Comment: @ADTC I found out I had to use single quotes for the searched string containing only special characters, else nothing will be found.
So this didn't return any result:
`grep --include=\*.php -FRn -e "$$"`
Using single quoutes gave me the wanted result:
`grep --include=\*.php -FRn -e '$$'`

Comment: @Piemol it could be because `$` has special meaning in `bash`, which takes precedence over `grep`. Single quote overrides that special meaning. **I'm not 100% sure though.**

Comment: You _are_ correct @ADTC. `$` and a few other characters are special and they will be replaced by bash after you hit enter and before `grep` (or whatever command) is executed. You can tell bash to leave all characters (except a single quote) untouched by enclosing them inside single quotes. If you need to type a single quote do it like this `'I'\''m special'`

Answer (score 20):

That's either `fgrep` or `grep -F` which will not do regular expressions. `fgrep` is identical to `grep -F` but I prefer to not have to worry about the arguments, being intrinsically lazy :-)

```
grep   ->  grep
fgrep  ->  grep -F  (fixed)
egrep  ->  grep -E  (extended)
rgrep  ->  grep -r  (recursive, on platforms that support it).
```

Comment: For GNU grep, fgrep is just provided as a symlink to grep which makes it take -F

Comment: `egrep` and `fgrep` are not specified by the POSIX standard; `grep -F` and `grep -E` [are](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)

Answer (score 4):

Pass `-F` to `grep`.

Comment: I read this as `Press F to grep` instead of what was actually written, which made me think it was like those `Press F to show respects` or  `Press X to doubt` memes. I should get off the internet...

Comment: You're not the only one @Wimateeka :)

Answer (score 3):

you can also use awk, as it has the ability to find fixed string, as well as programming capabilities, eg only

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i == "mystring") {print "do data manipulation here"} }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

I really like the `-P` flag available in GNU grep for selective ignoring of special characters.

It makes `grep -P "^some_prefix\Q[literal]\E$"` possible

from [grep manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

> -P, --perl-regexp
> Interpret I as Perl-compatible regular
> expressions (PCREs).  This option is experimental when
> combined with the -z (--null-data) option, and grep -P may
> warn of unimplemented features.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat list.txt
one:hello:world
two:2:nothello

three:3:kudos

grep --color=always -F"hello

three" list.txt
```

## output

```
one:hello:world
three:3:kudos
```

Comment: I don't agree. Its a useful illustration of how this works.