# Printing duplicate rows as many times it is duplicate in the input file using UNIX

Tags: file, unix, duplicates

Suppose I have a sorted file:

```
 AARAV,12345,BANK OF AMERICA,$145
 AARAV,12345,BANK OF AMERICA,$145
 AARAV,12345,BANK OF AMERICA,$145
 RAM,124455,DUETCHE BANK,$240
```

And I want output as:

```
 AARAV,12345,BANK OF AMERICA,$145
 AARAV,12345,BANK OF AMERICA,$145
```

With `**uniq -d file**` I am able to find duplicate records but its printing the record only once even if it is repeated. I want to print as many times it is duplicated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated to handle the spaces by switching to while loop.

Comment: Can anyone advise me here.. if input line has a star(*) or any regex character grep will not work. What else can I do here.

Comment: Try using `grep -F` isntead. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242873/grep-for-literal-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want, assuming your file is called `Input.txt`.

```
uniq -d Input.txt  | xargs -I {} grep   {} Input.txt
```

`xargs -I {}` basically tells `xargs` to substitute the input that is being piped in whenever it sees `{}` in a later command.

`grep {} Input.txt` will be called with each line of input from the pipe, where the line of input will get substituted where `{}` is.

Why does this work? We are using `uniq -d` to find the duplicate entries, and then using them as input patterns to `grep` to match all the lines which contain those entries. Thus, only duplicate entries are printed, and they are printed exactly as many times as they appear in the file.

**Update**: Printing the duplicates occurences only, not the first occurrence, in a way that is compatible with `ksh`, since the OP does not apparently have `bash` on his system.

```
uniq -d Input.txt | xargs -L 1 | while read line
do
    grep  "$line"  Input.txt | tail -n +2; 
done
```

Note that in the above scripts, we are assuming that no line is a substring of another line.

Comment: Hey can you please explain your command. What are these braces meant to do

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. With uniq we will find which rows are duplicate, and with grep we will search them in input file. Thats good but my requirement is not to print the first time it appears. Like 123 is present 4 times in input file. so, thrice it is duplicate. So it should come thrice not 4 times.

Comment: @Aarav, Updating again.

Comment: I m sorry.. I am writing this in unix shell script. But its giving me error..Am I interpreting this wrong.

Comment: @Aarav, I tested this the `bash` shell. What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using ksh shell.

Comment: @Aarav, Try typing `bash` on your command line, pushing `Enter` and then using the commands in my answer.

Comment: I dnt have bash in my system :-(

Comment: What flavor of *nix are you running? This is the first time I've heard of a nix without bash?

Comment: If you aren't sure, then `cat /etc/issue` *might* tell you.

Comment: @Aarav, I updated again with a solution that I tested in `ksh`. Throw it into a script and see if it also runs on your system.

Comment: This will work good with the above file but for a file having some 130 characters with a space in them. it will read it as new line when we encounter a space

Comment: You can't do multiline comments, you will have to update your question.

Comment: Updated the question with the actual data to process.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the output that you want. It repeats each duplicate line N-1 times. Unfortunately the output isn't sorted, so you'd have to pipe it through sort again.

Assuming the input file is `input.txt`:

`awk -F '\n' '{ a[$1]++ } END { for (b in a) { while(--a[b]) { print b } } }' input.txt | sort`

Comment: This is so great. But the example I have given is different. I have a big file having some 130 characters in a line with some space as well. This is not working for that.

Comment: Can you share an example of some data that doesn't work with it?

Comment: Example: AARAVA,ght,BANK OF AMERICA,123