# Grep for specific code block

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have this phantom block of code that is messing up my program, but I can simply NOT find where it is in my project. I know exactly (to the whitespace) what the code would be, but since it is code it has a lot of spaces, periods, brackets, ect. It would be a huge pain to type out a regular expression for the whole thing. Is there a way I could just search for an exact match to a string using `grep -r`?

Comment: for searching source codes I would use ag (silver searcher)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep for literal strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242873/grep-for-literal-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgrep` does this (or `grep -F`). Don't forget to quote the pattern to prevent the shell from interpreting it:

```
$ echo 'a' | grep '[abc]'
a
$ echo 'a' | fgrep '[abc]'
$ echo '[abc]' | fgrep '[abc]'
[abc]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a multiline pattern, `pcregrep -F` can be useful (`-F` for with fixed string).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that matches the markdown code block. I'm using [pcregrep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pcregrep.1.html) (old) and [pcre2grep](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2grep.html) (new)

### Context

**README.md**

````
## Installation

Install the application locally.    

```shell
pip install -r requirements.txt
flask run --host=$HOST --port=$PORT
```

## Test

End-to-end test.

```shell
curl "http://localhost"; echo
```
````

#### Solution

````
$ pcregrep -M '```[^`]*```' README.md 
```shell
pip install -r requirements.txt
flask run --host=$HOST --port=$PORT
```
```shell
curl "http://localhost"; echo
```

$ pcre2grep -M '```[^`]*```' README.md 
```shell
pip install -r requirements.txt
flask run --host=$HOST --port=$PORT
```
```shell
curl "http://localhost"; echo
```
````