# BASH cannot grep properly variable containing '\'

Tags: grep, backslash

I have got a variable containing `\` and cannot grep properly.

I am making a snippet to connect to wifi spots.

1. I scan all wifi spots and keep that info in `/tmp/wifi.spots`
2. then copy the spot I am interested in (with mouse right click)
3. then paste the spot name into an input command:
4. make some other things:

   a. grep /tmp/wifi.spots to select the ap with the best Quality (=70/70 if possible)

   b. grep /tmp/wifi.spots to configure wpa_conf if there is a password

Here is my code:

```
iwlist <wifi device> scan > /tmp/wifi.spots    

grep /tmp/wifi.spots | grep -i essid 


read -rp "what essid you want to connect to?" ESSID
```

Here comes the problem: Let's say I want to connect to a spot called "G\xC3\x92TIC". In order to grep correctly in /tmp/wifi.spots,I need to rewrite the ESSID variable to:
G\\xC3\\x92TIC

So what I need is the following. After having pasted my essid in ESSID, I need to check it out for any '\' and rewrite the variable if necessary before going through step 4.

Comment: Using `grep '\\'`, can you not avoid rewriting your variable ?

Comment: I think the grep -F solves your problem more elegant. [Grep for literal strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242873/grep-for-literal-strings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep for literal strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242873/grep-for-literal-strings)